# Flutter installation perplex on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, compiling, snap

Good day everyone. I have installed Flutter via snap. However, when I initiate any flutter command, flutter starts to download the SDK ([flutter_linux_1.17.5-stable.tar.xz](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_1.17.5-stable.tar.xz)) all over again. Is this normal? Isn't installation via snap meant to eliminate the process of download and building of source code?

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

I am on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but a possible work-around. You can see if the behavior is the same by installing it [manually](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux). Snap apps work in a sandbox with a variety of limited permissions. This seems to frequently cause issues not found when installing things by alternative means. The manual install instructions aren't all that complex and are clearly indicated at the linked site.

Comment: Thank you. I will try again using the manual version. I'd also like to ask, before trying the manual installation, do you recommend uninstalling the snap version?

Comment: Yeah, it's probably best to remove the snap version first.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I'll report my experience once I'm done.

Comment: You were definitely spot on with your suggestions. I removed the snap version and installed flutter manually. WORKED LIKE A CHARM!!!! Thank you! If you wouldn't mind, you can official add it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution to this question.

Comment: Consider it done. Hopefully it'll help other folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A current solution is to first remove the Snap app and to install Flutter manually. To remove Flutter, run `snap remove flutter` from the terminal.

Because the process is subject to change, it's best practice to link to the official directions.

[Install Flutter on Linux](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux)

**NOTE:** Before beginning, make sure you meet the requirements for tools, disk space, and libraries.